# How to insert current date in hive using insert command

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
insert into kb values(select current_date(),select current_timestamp());      
select * from kb;
```

It gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT ... SELECT:

```
insert into table kb select current_date(), current_timestamp();
```

Read the [language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML).

Comment: the second query (insert into table kb values (current_date, current_timestamp); ) is not working showing an error:                                                                                                
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values

Comment: @BhargavaRamkhythepalli Yes, checked it also, indeed does not work. The only option is INSERT ... SELECT then